# TFS 2017: only allow manual deployment to PROD environment after release to DEV and QA

Tags: tfs, release-management

In TFS, say I have 3 environments in my release definition:

1. DEV
2. QA
3. PROD

I only want TFS to permit **manual** deployment to PROD after successful deployments to DEV and QA.

I **do not** want the deployment to PROD to be automatic, and I do not want to use any approval mechanism.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the "**Trigger**" option for each environment:

Select the environment in release definition >> Click "**...**" behind the environment name (eg, Dev) >> **Deployment Conditions...** >> Set the trigger option for each environment as following:

- DEV : After release creation
- QA  : After successful deployment to another environment, select DEV
  for triggering environment(s).
- PROD: No automated deployment

But there isn't the option to disable approval mechanism. However you can set the `Pre-deployment approver` and `Post-deployment approver` as `Automatic`, thus the system will automatically approve the deployments.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to make promoting to DEV then QA mandatory first, 
Then we cannot achieve that as all the three environments are using the same artifacts in release.

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy, I've already got these settings. However this lets me deploy to Production without promoting to DEV or QA first. I want to make promoting to DEV then QA mandatory first, for the following reasons: (a) Code is peer tested using development env  (b) Code is tested by QA.   I have a feeling this isn't going to be do-able OOB.

Comment: @Scott Yeah, unfortunately, we cannot achieve that as all the three environments are using the same artifacts in release.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT Isn't it a serious limitation if such a sequence (Dev => QA => Production) can't be enforced?